# Is "I have Asperger syndrome" grammatically correct?

Tags: british-english

I'm trying to write my first book. In it, the protagonist has Asperger syndrome. It was going well until I encountered this sentence (the boy is confessing to another person) and became confused.

Is it a coherent sentence? Are there any other appropriate ways to say this?

Comment: I see a perfectly good answer below, but you say it's not the answer you're seeking. Perhaps you can clarify what problem you're having with the sentence?

Comment: I expected an explicit answer.

Comment: That answer doesn't help. If you can't clarify, we can't help you.

Comment: *"I have autism/Asperger syndrome (with or without the apostrophe)/ADAH/.."*etc. You can shorten the phrase to: "I have Asperger's" and it will be understood.

Comment: But is it appropriate to say "Asperger syndrome" in British English?

Comment: Yes, it's probably the most common way to refer it but both forms are used and understood. The shortened form should have the apostrophe http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/medical_examiner/2013/05/autism_spectrum_diagnoses_the_dsm_5_eliminates_asperger_s_and_pdd_nos.html (I was going to answer your question but it seems pointless now)

Comment: Yes, it is. The syndrome is known as Asperger(s) in all major English speaking regions, including [GB]9http://www.autism.org.uk/about-autism/autism-and-asperger-syndrome-an-introduction/what-is-asperger-syndrome.aspx).

Comment: I'll just change the original line to "I have Asperger's" this wouldn't cause confusion, I suppose.

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary of English calls it 'Asperger's Syndrome', meaning: 'A rare and relatively mild autistic disorder characterised by awkwardness in social interaction, pedantry in speech,and preoccupation with very narrow interests. Named after Hans Asperger (1906-1980) the Austrian psychiatrist who described the condition in 1944.'    I believe it is also frequently a high-functioning disorder, with sufferers achieving brilliant levels of accomplishment in narrow fields. In Haddon's novel the boy excels in mathematics.

Comment: @Nick, I would certainly advise you to shorten it. In the context of someone, especially someone young enough to be described as a boy, saying “I _have_ [it]” to a friend, the fairly technical and clinical-sounding word ‘syndrome’ is very likely to be left out. I have two fellow students who have Asperger’s, and that is how they both say it—without ‘syndrome’. I would only include ‘syndrome’ if describing someone else in a more technical or clinical manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Britain we would say Asperger's syndrome.

Presumably you have read Mark Haddon's 'The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time' (2003), a novel dealing with the very subject upon which you are embarking, a teenage boy who has severe Asperger's syndrome. The book is currently adapted as a stage play in the West End, and has apparently been a great support to parents of children with the condition.

I would think it is essential reading to someone about to embark on a similar project.

Has anyone close to you been affected by Asperger's?

Comment: My first cousin has severe Asperger's syndrome, thanks for pointing out how it's said in Britian, my first language isn't English. But this does not, however, answer my question.

Comment: Your question was whether 'I have Asperger syndrome' is grammatically correct, wasn't it? Well, yes, it's perfectly correct,except for the apostrophe and the .. s. What is your first language, Nick?

Comment: It's Spanish. I failed to comprehend your answer when I first read it, I didn't know you implied the answer, my apologies.

Comment: @Nick read Mark Haddon, you will find the book very interesting.

Comment: I took your advice and went through the book. You were right, its theme is similar to that of mine's. On the plus side, it also has some vocabulary that would fit perfectly. And now I can handle that _other_ matter without hassle.

Comment: @Nick Excellent news!